# sql to python: how to group a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a big list of Ids of items that I put in a list of dictionaries:

```
[
{ 'product1': 2, 'item1':4,'product2':333,'item2':222},
{ 'product1': 1, 'item1':123,'product2':333,'item2':222},
{ 'product1': 3, 'item1':433,'product2':333,'item2':222},
{ 'product1': 3, 'item1':433,'product2':333,'item2':224},
]
```

I need to check if the generation of that values worked well and generally build some stats.

A slow approach would be to save all on a database (SQLite) and use SQL. For example:

```
select *, count(*) as cnt from the mytable group by product1,item1 order by cnt desc;
```

I wonder if there is a faster way in python to do the same thing as that SQL. I will basically need to be able to filter the data, and the above SQL seems the most difficult thing I have to translate in python3.

Comment: i would guess that you could check pandas and numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas for that:

```
import pandas

data = [
    { 'product1': 2, 'item1':4,'product2':333,'item2':222},
    { 'product1': 1, 'item1':123,'product2':333,'item2':222},
    { 'product1': 3, 'item1':433,'product2':333,'item2':222},
    { 'product1': 3, 'item1':433,'product2':333,'item2':224},
]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
grouped = df.groupby(['product1', 'item1']).count()
sorted = grouped.sort_values('item2', ascending=False)
```

This doesn't give you a single `cnt` column, but all columns that are not in the group-by clause will contain the count. This can be helpful if different column contain `NaN`'s.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with the NaN's columns. You mean when product1 or item1 does not exists (NaN), right? Otherwise I don't see how product2 item2 existence should modify the counts.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. In this example it doesn't matter, I just wanted to point out that the count refers to the number of non-NaN elements and not rows.

Comment: In my case there won't be dictionaries without product2 or item2, but I'm not sure if I understand all possible cases.